# Taking info from list in dictionary

Tags: python, list

I have next code:

```
ind=[{'id':123,'name'='Andrew','universities':[{'country'=123,'state'=123}], school=[{'name'=Beliech,'state'=...}],'type'=[{}] }]
```

I need to take name of the school in the school field, and state with country in universities field to add it into data base. I tried to convert list ind into dictionary (info=ind[0]) and then take info, but I got problem, that school is a list too, so I can't use `ind['school']['name']`. Universities and school are not static, they can replace each other and stay at the beggining/end/middle. How can I take this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas
ind=[{'id':123,'name':'Andrew','universities':[{'country':123,'state':1234}], 'school':[{'name':"Beliech"}]}]
name_list = []
school_name_list = []
university_country_list = []
university_state_list = []
for i in range(len(ind)):
    name_list.append(ind[i]['name'])
    school_name_list.append(ind[i]['school'][0]['name'])
    university_country_list.append(ind[i]['universities'][0]['country'])
    university_state_list.append(ind[i]['universities'][0]['state'])
Output = pandas.DataFrame({'Name':name_list,'School_Name':school_name_list,'University_Country':university_country_list,'University_State':university_state_list})
```

I was not exactly clear with the question. based on my understanding, this is what i could come up with

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer you, but I couldn't actually understand some points.

```
ind = [{'id':123, 'name':'Andrew','universities':[{'country':123,'state':123}], 'school':[{'name':'Beliech','state':...}],'type':[{}]}]

list_dict = []
for index in range (0, len(ind[0]["school"])):
    new_dict = {
        "School_Name" :  ind[0]["school"][index]["name"],
        "University_Country": ind[0]["universities"][index]["country"],
        "University_State": ind[0]["universities"][index]["state"],
    }
    list_dict.append(new_dict)
```

I just create a dictionary for each school, to which a university is associated. In your example, the school Beliech is associated with the University in the Country 123 and in the State 123. All the dictionaries are stored in a list.
I don't know if this is actually what you're looking for. I hope so.

Please, pay attention to dictionary keys. You wrote school and Beliech as two variables and not as strings. I think it's not what you want.

**EDIT**

I hope it will be what you're looking for. If not, try to be more exact, please:

```
ind = [{'id':123, 'name':'Andrew','universities':[{'country':123,'state':123}], 'school':[{'name':'Beliech','state':...}],'type':[{}]}]

user_name = input("Please, enter your name")

for index in range (0, len(ind)):
    if ind[index]["name"] == user_name:
        dict = ind[index]
        school_list = []
        for school in range(0, len(dict["school"])):
            school_list.append(dict["school"][school]["name"])
        university_list = []  # list of dictionary with all the info about a University
        universitycountry_list = []
        universitystate_list = []
        for uni in range(0, len(dict["universities"])):
            university_list.append(dict["universities"][uni])
            universitycountry_list.append(dict["universities"][uni]["country"])
            universitystate_list.append(dict["universities"][uni]["state"])
        found = True
        break
    else:
        found = False

if not found:
    print("The user {} is not in the Database".format(user_name))

# print(school_list)
# print(university_list)
# print(universitycountry_list)
# print(universitystate_list)
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, my bad. This list is user's personal info. From the list I need separately grab info from school and university to add it to db. There is no connection between them. State can diffrent or there can be no state at all.

Comment: So would you have access to school_name, university_country, university_state (that could be all lists) from the name, in your example "Andrew"?

Comment: I don't know user's name before. My whole script is collecting data by user's Id or profile url(depends on profile) using API. This list is result of script.